# Cannot install package from github

Tags: python, git

I try to install a github package using pip install git+url, but the following error keeps popped out. Anyone can help me figure it out?
[image]

Comment: Can u try , ` pip install <repo url> `

Answer (score 2):

A pip install would expect a setup.py file to execute after a clone.

But [`fchollet/deep-learning-models`](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models) does not have such a file, hence the error message.
Note that its README includes:

> THIS REPOSITORY IS DEPRECATED. USE THE MODULE [`keras.applications`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras-resources) INSTEAD.